# Solving a second order differential equation to obtain trajectories

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I don't know if this is appropriate to ask so please let me know if I should keep this post or not.

While calculating some accelerated trajectories, i encountered a rather tedious differential equation of the form,
$$  \frac{da^0}{d\tau} + \frac{\Big(\mu - \frac{GQ^2}{r}  \Big) }{GQ^2 + r^2 - 2r\mu} (u^0 a^1 + u^1 a^0) = \vert a \vert^2 u^0$$
where, $u^i$ is a 4-vector of velocity (dependent on $\tau$), $G$, $Q$ can be treated as constants along with $\mu$ and $r$ is a variable. Here, $a^i$ is the acceleration 4-vector and the expression for which is,

$$a^0 = \frac{du^0}{d\tau} + \frac{2\Big(\mu - \frac{GQ^2}{r}  \Big) }{GQ^2 + r^2 - 2r\mu} (u^1 u^0)\\
a^1 = \frac{du^1}{d\tau} - \frac {(Mr-Q^{2})}{r^{2}-2Mr+Q^{2}}(u^0)^2 + \frac {Q^{2}-Mr}{Q^{2}r-2Mr^{2}+r^{3}} (u^1)^2$$
So, after combining these equations (where $\vert a \vert^2$ is also a constant ) and substituting the later expressions into the former equation,we get a long differential equation like,

$$\frac{d}{d\tau} \Big(\frac{du^0}{d\tau} + \frac{2\Big(\mu - \frac{GQ^2}{r}  \Big) }{GQ^2 + r^2 - 2r\mu} (u^1 u^0)\Big) +  \frac{\Big(\mu - \frac{GQ^2}{r}  \Big) }{GQ^2 + r^2 - 2r\mu} \Bigg(u^0 \Big( \frac{du^1}{d\tau} - \frac {(Mr-Q^{2})}{r^{2}-2Mr+Q^{2}}(u^0)^2 + \frac {Q^{2}-Mr}{Q^{2}r-2Mr^{2}+r^{3}} (u^1)^2\Big) + u^1 \Big(\frac{du^0}{d\tau} + \frac{2\Big(\mu - \frac{GQ^2}{r}  \Big) }{GQ^2 + r^2 - 2r\mu} (u^1 u^0)\Big)\Bigg) = \vert a \vert^2 u^0 $$

which I am not getting anywhere with. Any help/clue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I think the additional information about the $a^1$ equation could be needed.
$$  \frac{da^1}{d\tau} =  \vert a \vert^2 u^1$$

Comment: To clarify. So you have $u^0 (\tau)$, $u^1 (\tau)$ and $r (\tau)$ as three functions you are trying to solve for? And you are at fixed $x^2=\theta$, $x^3=\phi$?

Comment: Yes. I want to solve for the $u^1$ in this case. I have not provided the equation for $u^0$ though here.

Comment: [Relevant Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.04674.pdf)

Comment: My first suggestion is to stop hauling around such a huge baggage of notation. Set $$F(\tau) =\frac{\Big(\mu - \frac{GQ^2}{r}  \Big) }{GQ^2 + r^2 - 2r\mu}\\G(\tau) = \frac {(Mr-Q^{2})}{r^{2}-2Mr+Q^{2}}\\H(\tau) = \frac {Q^{2}-Mr}{Q^{2}r-2Mr^{2}+r^{3}} = \frac Gr$$ Maybe even let $y = u^0, z =u^1$. Just this step will hide a lot of stuff that isn't directly important to manipulating the differential equation, and allow you to more easily see how to solve it.

Comment: @AHusain In the paper, authors have used the trick of $u^i u_i = 1$ to solve for the second component. I want to solve this equation directly (if possible in any way)

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am using those notations when solving "on paper"